# How do I make a simple bus route search Engine?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web

[Not:e user is asking this again at [Development of railway enquiry system, how to model Trains, Stations and Stops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273234/development-of-railway-enquiry-system-need-attention-in-databse/8273433#8273433) ]
**My Problem Description:**

Suppose I have a **BUS-123 in ROUTE-1** it will travel through A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H and **BUS-321 in ROUTE-2** through D, E, F, **X, Y, Z** .
if someone enters B as a source point and F as a destination point then ROUTE-1 with BUS-123 should display in the result. But if someone enters H as a source and A as destination result should not display, because returning may not always same with one that is traveled.
But if a person enters A as a source and Z as destination then **BUS-123** with **ROUTE-1** and **BUS-321** with **ROUTE-2** should display.

My Problem is:
How do I store that route information in Database? if i store in RDBMS like the following

```
BUS_NUMBER   ROUTE_NUMBER    VIA_ROUTES
BUS-123      ROUTE-1         A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
BUS-321      ROUTE-2         D, E, F, X, Y, Z
```

Then how my search will work. I mean how to search it in a string.
And if I store all the VIA_ROUTES in different different columns then how it will be..? Please suggest me with your own technique. It is not urgent but I am planning to make a basic bus route search, so your comment with help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a "simple" answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing your homework your self?

Comment: this is not my homework.

Comment: What would you do when you have another Bus-456 with Route-5 that goes through P, Q, R, S and someone wants to travel from C to R? Would you display Bus-123 and Bus-456?

Comment: Can you rephrase that, so it makes sense: `because returning may not always same with one that is traveled.`

Comment: in one way roads sometimes A to B and B to A will be different.so considering this in mind i was saying like that, my English is not good but i was meant to say like that only.

Comment: @Raihan it will simply does not show the result, because there is no related data with that ROUTE-5 with other routes, i mean no intermediate stops that link between ROUTE-1 and ROUTE-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd model it as a cyclic graph. Each bus stop is represented by a vertice. Each direct connection between two stops is represented by an edge labelled with the route number; consequently, each route is a sequence of connected edges. Make the edges directed, too. Not all routes travelling from stop A to stop B will necessarily also travel from stop B to stop A in the other direction.

Probably want to populate each edge with the estimated travel time, a measure (or measures) of variance for that leg -- at 2am on a Sunday night, the variance might be low, but at 5pm on a Friday evening, it might be very high, and list of departure times as well.

Then its a matter of graph traversal and finding the "least cost" route, however you choose to define "least cost" -- Factors you might want to consider would include:

- Total travel time
- Total time spent waiting for the next leg to depart.
- Wait time at any individual stop.
- Distance?

One should note that too much wait time is bad (ever spend 40 minutes waiting for a bus in January when it's -10 F?). Too little is bad, too, as it increases the probability of missing a connection, given that buses tend to have a fairly large variability to their schedules since they are highly responsive to fluctuations in local traffic conditions.

That's how I would do it.

I don't believe I'd try to solve it directly in SQL, though.

The model is a good fit for SQL, though. You need the following entities, and then some, since you'll need to represent schedules, etc.:

- **Stop.** A Bus stop. The vertices of the graph.
- **Route.** A bus route.
- **Segment**. The direct link between two stops. The edges of the graph.
- **RouteSegment.** An associative entity representing ordered sequence of segments that composes the route.

Comment: Do you prefer a DFS over a dijkestra? What kind of graph traversal do you mean?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have read it carefully and i will adjust with my current table. Your suggestion is nice while i was considering with very few entities. Cheers for you also.

Comment: +1 for mentioning journey cost. I would much rather take one journey that takes 30 minutes even if two concatenated routes took 25 minutes in total, especially if it is cold outside :)

Comment: The answer mentions about vertex and directed edges, but does not mention about using graph database like Neo4j. I don't know how to use graph database, but I believe this problem perfectly fits into category of problems that graph database solve. RDBMS may not be the best solution here considering the complexity of searches from node to node.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bus_numbers aren't important because you can look them up later. Maybe what you need is to create a 2d matrix with the bus_stops in a big matrix having them all and then use a graph traversing algorithm like dijkstra to find the shortest path from A to B. When you got that you can easily lookup the bus_numbers and show them to the client. Thus I think your database is already very good.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, yes your answer is quite helpful, i will try to find out a solution with the 2d matrix and dijkstra kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a `route` table and a `route_part` table. The latter would contain a reference to the route, plus an ordinal number for sorting, and a reference to a `stop` table. Thus, you can store any route.

In terms of searching, if you wish to search for a route between two stops, you could look up the two stops in the `route_part` table and see if they appear on the same route in any cases (bearing in mind that a route may exist in one direction and not the other).

Comment: Looking for the same route isn't like compute the shortest path.

Comment: @user1054582 - no probs. I didn't spot your requirement however to link routes together, so as per David's answer, a network traversal algorithm of some kind will be necessary.