# Development of railway enquiry system, how to model Trains, Stations and Stops?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, model

For example, if I have two trains, X and Y and they travel:

TRAIN.........STATIONS

- Train-X : Goes Via Station-A; Station-B; Station-C; Station-D
- Train-Y : Goes Via Station-B; Station-X; Station-D; Station-Y

How would I go about putting this information in a database so that if a passenger inquired about **What trains start as Station-B?** and **What trains End as Station-D?** then both Train-X and Train-Y should come in the result.

Comment: Same question by same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189245/how-do-i-make-a-simple-bus-route-search-engine

Comment: changed the title and wording a bit for clarity, e.g. train X instead of Train A as confusion potential given 'Station A'

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to have three tables to make this work.

**Station**: station ID, name, etc.

**Service**: service ID, operator, number of train cars perhaps, etc.

**Service_Stop**: service ID, stop number, station ID.

You can then find services that stop at Station-B and subsequently at Station-D using a query something like the following:

```
SELECT
    Service_ID
FROM
    Station AS Start_Station
    JOIN Service_Stop AS Start_Stop ON
        Start_Station.Station_ID = Start_Stop.Station_ID
    JOIN Service_Stop AS End_Stop ON
        Start_Stop.Service_ID = End_Stop.Service_ID AND
        Start_Stop.Stop_Number < End_Stop.Stop_Number
    JOIN Station AS End_Station ON
        End_Stop.Station_ID = End_Station.Station_ID AND
        End_Station.Name = "Station-D"
WHERE
    Start_Station.Name = 'Station-B'
```

Comment: how this service id,operator,number of train helps and service stops contain what type of relation with that route?

Comment: I don't know. It just seems sensible to have a table whose rows represent train journeys, to which Service_Stop.Service_ID can be a foreign key.

Comment: the query part is useful, but i am not understanding the database table part, suppose in that station table, all the stations id will be stored, in service and service stops i could not find what to stored and how can i put intermediate via routes...

Comment: Each row in Service_Stop represents the statement, "Service `X` stops at Station `Y`, and moreover Station `Y` is the `Z`th stop for Service `X`".

Answer (score 1):

I would use five tables:.

```
Train: train_id, name   # e.g "The UnionT522"
Station: station_id, name # e.g. "Eggles Place"
Route: route_id, route_name # e.g. "Afternoon special at 4pm" 
RouteStation: route_station_id, route_id, station_id, route_order, begin_flag, end_flag
TrainRoute: train_route_id, train_id, route_id  # e.g. which train (above) is going on which route (above).
```

So `RouteStation` would have whether things began or ended at a given station for a given route.
`TrainRoute` would have information about which route a train is taking.

Comment: thanks a lot for this helpful answer, can you explain what that begin_flag and end_flag will do?

Comment: it gets combined with the route_order so if a route is 4 stations you'll have 4 rows, 1 will have begin_flag set (route_order is 1), the next 2 rows will have neither flag set (route_order 2 and 3), the 4th will have the end_flag set (route order 4).  This way you can construct good 'route' information using appropriate joins with this data structure.

Comment: "have neither flag set " -> "have neither flag set (or set to false/N) "

Comment: Hammerite's answer is purer and I'm sure would work fine.  Some folks may find mine more readable / maintainable.  As with all things "it depends where you are going with this..."

Comment: ok...one more doubt...in the **RouteStation** each row contains different routes right, but how can i store all the via routes...in that table?

Comment: For a given Route with 4 stops there are 4 records (as I described) and each one has the same Route ID.  Then you 'build' routes by using those records (and the route_order field puts them in... you guessed it!)

Comment: I added RouteStation ID to the RouteStation table and also TrainRouteID to the TrainRoute tables.  These would be their primary keys.  They could also be called ID in each table (RubyOnRails for example uses that convention).

Comment: underscore'd and lowercase'd all the id names I think train_station_id is better than Train Station ID even if spaces are allowed in column names (often not).

Comment: Your employer is having you design this on Stack Overflow?  Man i don't wanna be on those trains !

Comment: clarity: the route_order field CAN be used to put them n order whn used in a sql select 'ORDER' clause (but has to be done explicitly).