# Calculating Most Efficient Transit Route Using Transit Data

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have the transit data for my city and I want to build a tool in PHP that allows a user to select two bus stops on the map and then have the application calculate an efficient route, on the city's transit system, from stop A to stop B. The route from stop A to stop B may involve transferring busses at certain stops in order to reach the final destination.

I have data for bus stop locations, bus stop times, route and trip information for my city:

*Routes:* http://openregina.cloudapp.net/DataBrowser/OpenRegina/TransitRoutes

*Stops:* http://openregina.cloudapp.net/DataBrowser/OpenRegina/TransitStops

*Stop Times:* http://openregina.cloudapp.net/DataBrowser/OpenRegina/TransitStopTimes

*Trips:* http://openregina.cloudapp.net/DataBrowser/OpenRegina/TransitTrips

I've pulled the above data into my own MySQL database.

**Using this data, how can I calculate an efficient route from stop A to stop B?**

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, as I really have no idea what the best approach is for my case. Thought I'd ask Stack Overflow for their input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a big graph where each bus stop is represented by a vertex and each direct connection by an edge. Then you can look for the cheapest or fastest or shortest or a combinations of all of them by a depth-first search. Look here: [How do I make a simple bus route search Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189245/how-do-i-make-a-simple-bus-route-search-engine/8189349#8189349).